# Adding Apache Camel custom component/endpoint in a Spring application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-camel

I'm trying to implement a custom endpoint in a Spring Boot application.

Goal is to use routes as: `from("...").process("...").to("my:...");`

Now, I have 3 classes: a DefaultConsumer, a DefaultEndpoint, a DefaultComponent:

```
package com.my.endpoint;

import org.apache.camel.Consumer;
import org.apache.camel.Processor;
import org.apache.camel.Producer;
import org.apache.camel.support.DefaultEndpoint;

public class MyEndpoint extends DefaultEndpoint {

    public MyEndpoint(String uri, MyComponent myComponent) {

    }
    ...
}
```

```
package com.my.endpoint;

import org.apache.camel.Endpoint;
import org.apache.camel.Processor;
import org.apache.camel.support.DefaultConsumer;

public class MyConsumer extends DefaultConsumer {

    public MyConsumer(Endpoint endpoint, Processor processor) {

        super(endpoint, processor);
    }
}
```

```
package com.my.endpoint;

import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.Endpoint;
import org.apache.camel.spi.annotations.Component;
import org.apache.camel.support.DefaultComponent;

import java.util.Map;

@Component("my")
public class MyComponent extends DefaultComponent {

    public MyComponent(CamelContext camelContext) {

        super(camelContext);
    }
    ...
}
```

Now: how can I register?

In a Spring configuration class, I have:

```
  @Override
  public void configure() throws Exception {

        camelContext.addComponent("my", new MyComponent(camelContext));
```

But is not working:

```
    Caused by: org.apache.camel.NoSuchEndpointException: No endpoint could be found for: my, please check your classpath contains the needed Camel component jar.
```

So, I added the META-INF file in services/org/apache/camel/component/my:

```
class=com.my.endpoint.MyComponent
```

But also this, is not working.

There is no complete tutorial on how to implement this.

Any help?

Note: I'm trying to implement an Endpoint because I need to integrate my systems using my data types. I tried using Transformer but failed because of this: [Set a custom DataType in Apache Camel Processor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66645889/set-a-custom-datatype-in-apache-camel-processor)

Before, I tried using data type converter, but failed because of this (marked duplicate because people are too lazy to really understand questions): [Enforce type conversion on Rest consumer in Apache Camel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66603690/enforce-type-conversion-on-rest-consumer-in-apache-camel)

I've FULLY read "Apache Camel In Action, Second Edition" but, at the moment, I can't continue with my project because of?

Comment: Did you try UriEndpointComponent instead of DefaultComponent?

Comment: @StepanShcherbakov there is no such class: Deprecated. 
use DefaultComponent

Comment: Sorry, i didnt notice

Comment: I am not really sure, but may be you shoul add @ UriEndpoint annotation to your component class and @ UriParam for uri parameters

Comment: Yes, @StepanShcherbakov. With UriEndpoint registration works. I was thinking was optional and only for documentation support, but no. Thank you.

Comment: Your welcome :) I also added answer, it may be helpful for users

Comment: Do you find solution @Vinz486

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because custom component must be annotated by `@UriEndpoint` annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve this problem: Set EndpointUri via Constructor or by implementing createEndpointUri() in MyEndpoint.

So easiest way might be changing your constructor to:

```
public MyEndpoint(String uri, MyComponent myComponent) {
 super(uri, myComponent);
}
```